# Laravel intelephense keeps saying that method is not defined in the model when in fact it is?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So, I'm using this line to create posts and relate them to the user

```php
// PostController
Auth::user()->posts()->create($inputs);
```

The problem is that intelephense keeps saying to me that `posts()` method doesn't exist in the user model, but I have it defined

```php
// User model
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Command is working fine, but it could cause me some problems in the future, so I would like to know if there is something I'm doing wrong or is it the intelephense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Intellephense](https://intelephense.com/) isn't a Laravel feature or package, it's a language server for PHP which is installed automatically along its extension in your editor or IDE

The analyzer has no way of knowing about Laravel facades, fluent and magic methods

So what you can do is generate those references for it using [barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

- Install the package as a development requirement

```
composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
```

- Automatic PHPDoc generation for Laravel Facades

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

- Automatic PHPDocs for models

```
php artisan ide-helper:models "App\Models\User"
```